# The mongoose.connect function gives error message

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

This is code for connection but I get error message everytime. I have included the mongoURI in `default.json` file but I am unable to detect the main problem here

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
        console.log('Mongodb connected ....');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error message');
        process.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly send the error message or your console logs?

Comment: i dont get any trace of the error it just displays the error message from catch

Comment: put he console.log(err) in the catch and the error  message will shown in the console

Comment: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: I chnaged the IP address settings at mongodb thanks @SulemanKhalid for the help